# error using json_encode on a string returned from a mySQL query

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to pass an array which is the result of a mySQL PDO query from php to javascript using json_encode.

However if one of the fields contains spaces, or, if I try to use a database function on the string (to select only the first non-space part), the object seems to be nonexistent, and my code does not compile.

Following is the executed code:

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT id, substring_index(firstNames, ' ', 1) as firstName, lastName, gender, idPersonFather, idPersonMother
  FROM a_person";

  $result = $db->query($sql);
  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

  $personArray[$row['id']] = Array(     'firstName' => $row['firstName']
                                    , 'lastName' => $row['lastName']
                                    , 'gender' => $row['gender']
                                    , 'idFather' => $row['idPersonFather']
                                    , 'idMother' => $row['idPersonMother']);
}
?>

<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/includes/grid_classes.js">

  var personArray=<?php echo json_encode($personArray); ?>//get php aray
  var someNextStuff
  ...etc
```

This will result in the error 
    `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`
because the line `var someNextStuff` comes unexpected, apparently the object is translated into an empty string?

Also, the following select causes the same problem:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstNames, lastName, gender, idPersonFather, idPersonMother
FROM a_person";
```

with firstNames containing values like 'Maria Anna Cecilia', and NULLs.

The SQL queries work on the database directly however (in phpmyadmin).

However, if I leave out the `firstNames` field from the select and the array, the code is working correctly.

What could be causing this?

thanks for your help..

Edit:

I now found that

```
SELECT id, substring_index(coalesce('Maria anna blah','?'), ' ', 1) as firstName, <rest of fields>
```

works, but

```
SELECT id, substring_index(coalesce(firstNames,'?'), ' ', 1) as firstName, <rest of fields>
```

does not.

So it has to be something with that field, I guess..

Comment: It looks like you're mixing PHP and JavaScript without appropriately separating them with `<?php` and `?>` tags, which is what's causing that syntax error...

Comment: Sorry, I left out the separators in the example - now added.. as mentioned, the code does compile and work properly as long as i leave out the field containing spaces.

Comment: Oh, okay, well then it looks like you need a semicolon right after `<?php echo json_encode($personArray); ?>` in the JavaScript.

Comment: I use as a coding standard no semicolons in javascript... As mentioned, the code does compile and work except when I add that field that contains spaces :)

Comment: I'd recommend abandoning that code standard. It is legal in JavaScript for a single statement to break across multiple lines, so if you don't have semicolons at the end of your statements, the JS interpreter might not realize that you're trying to start a new statement. I'm pretty sure that's what's happening here. If you really can't stand semicolons, you could look into using CoffeeScript.

Comment: adding the semicolon gives: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;. As mentioned twice, the code works when I leave out the field containing strings.

Comment: I'd assume that something with your query might be wrong, when no rows are produced the `json_encode` is naturally empty. You should probably check  `$result === false` and in that case output the error message in `$db->errorInfo()`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the right direction. Updated the Question.

Comment: you're coalescing (I love that word!) `firstNames` but elsewhere you refer to it as `firstName` (i do this all the time) but maybe that just came through in the write up here. just passing through.

Comment: Hi Sam, sorry - that was just a typo in the example on my behalf ... I am cutting firstnames into firstname, and just mixed up. But i think I found a source of the problem, see edit 2

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly the problem. If hard coded string works fine probably it might be the wrong data in db table. Check firstName field data for make sure it's not containing space before the name

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output of [`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/json_last_error_msg) (or just `json_last_error` if you are using an old PHP version, in which case you will only get an integer that you need to match to a constant), you will get one of these errors:

> Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded

or

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

The two weird characters you found (Ã and unprintable) are what happens when you try to store UTF-8 data in a database that is not using UTF-8 encoding.

You can try to work around this by calling [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) on each piece of data that might have unicode characters.

However, the best way to fix it is to make sure that your database is using UTF-8.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the helpful comments. Collation of the database is utf8_general_ci, however I do not think the HEX code C289 is anything in any character set that fits within UTF8. It is data that I exported from a family tree software program in GEDCOM format and I wrote a package to process a GEDCOM file and populate the mysql database. It may be that I overlooked setting UTF8 somewhere but I suspect that the data landed in the file incorrectly already. In all cases, I would only expect common characters so it is most likely dirty data...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I seems that it was indeed a false value in one of the rows in that field! (thanks Jakumi)

Patiently added more rows to the array from an ordered select until it failed, and that happens when adding the record with firstnames `Ãline`.
Copy Pasting I just found out that there is an unreadable character after The Ã...0089 whatever that is...
HEX c289
However just removing the value after the `Ã` character was not enough, it seems that my character set is maybe too limited. However I suspect this is dirty data, so it will go back to the source instead of me expanding the character set..